# Компиляция jar-файла из консоли с зависимым классом, находясь уровнем выше

Tags: java, компиляция, jar, git-cmd

В папке TaskBox есть папка TaskBox_v4 в ней есть cost-calc.jar с зависимым файлом Table.java.

Пробовал в git bash:

```
javac -cp "./TaskBox_v4;/TaskBox_v4/cost-calc.jar" ./TaskBox_v4/Table.java
```

В документации запутался.

Хочу узнать как запускать такое, **находясь на уровень выше**, если мы в папке TaskBox_v4 то всё просто:

```
javac -cp ".;/cost-calc.jar" Table.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам угадал

```
javac -cp "./TaskBox_v4/.;./TaskBox_v4/cost-calc.jar" ./TaskBox_v4/Table.java
```